# No DNS resolve on intranet clients when internet modem has disconnected from internet

Tags: dns, resolvconf

This is a very peculiar issue. I have a SOHO in my home that looks roughly like this:

```
internet->-|ISPmodem|->-|Firewall/DHCP/DNS/HTTP server|->-intranet
```

where

- ISP modem is not used as a router at all, and is configured as DMZ, with open firewall
- my server is doing the firewall/routing work and at the same time acts as a DHCP and DNS(bind) resolver for all intranet. Naturally it also acts as the gateway to the internet for all the intranet.
- Intranet includes desktops/laptops/printers/access points/etc, which include services like some HTTP servers, MPD (music player daemon), VNC servers , raspberry pi's, the list goes on.

While modem is connected to the internet, resolving any intranet and internet address and pinging them works fine. Any additional services such as using the FQDN to view the webpage of the HTTP server in my intranet , or using the FQDN of my MPD from some MPC (music player control) to change songs  works fine too. The same for everything. I say all that to basically say that I *think* I have setup the DHCP/DNS part correctly.

Now if I have no internet I would expect that all intranet services would continue being resolvable during the outage, but this seems to not be the case. I can still use everything in the intranet if I use their IP address instead of the FQDN. I can also run `nslookup <hostname|FQDN>` to resolve the ip address of some server and I will see in `tcpdump` that my request did reach the DNS server and a response was sent back fine. But trying to access the "service" normally, simply fails.
So if I try to use "Firefox" to view the webpage of the HTTP server for example , that fails with "cannot find page" error. Likewise for MPD, or when I try to `ssh` to other GNU/Linux IoT or embedded computers. The problem is always that the server is each case cannot be found.

This is very peculiar for me because I would expect that all intranet services should be working - the DNS server is a DNS "master" and acts authoritatively for the intranet domain.

This becomes even more peculiar because I have been tracking the activity of resolving with `tcpdump` and **have realized that no DNS requests have been forwarded to the DNS server when a see those "server not found" error messages**! It is as if the clients (all intranet pcs!) have decided that "since we cannot resolve the vast majority of our internet requests, there is no point trying to request anything at all".

I know this sounds silly but I literally have no idea why no resolving takes place! I cannot even narrow down this problem to ,say, the DNS server or some other component or some access point.

Could you please help? I have attached here my `named.conf` as a starting point. Perhaps there is indeed some important option missing. If you think some other information will help to draw some conclusions please do not hesitate to ask !

```
$ cat /etc/named.conf

include "/etc/rndc.key";

acl skails_dns {
        192.168.12.122/32;
        };

acl outbound_subnet { 192.168.321.0/24; }; //this is the modem subnet side
acl skails_subnet { 192.168.12.0/24; };    //this is the intranet side
acl local_host { 127.0.0.1/32; };
acl local_nets {
    local_host;
    skails_subnet;
    };
acl other_subnets { outbound_subnet; };
acl trusted_subnets {
    local_nets;
    skails_dns;
    };
acl all_my_nets {
    trusted_subnets;
    other_subnets;
    };

options {
    directory "/var/named";
    /*
     * If there is a firewall between you and name servers you want
     * to talk to, you might need to un-comment the query-source
     * directive below.  Previous versions of BIND always asked
     * questions using port 53, but BIND 8.1 uses an unprivileged
     * port by default.
     */
    // query-source address * port 53;
    forwarders {
        192.168.321.72;     //modem
        .....               //some other servers (openDNS, google, others)
        };
//  forward first;

    allow-recursion { trusted_subnets; }; //for whom will bind go the extra mile to find the final address
    listen-on { trusted_subnets; }; //ifs on which bind listens for queries
    allow-transfer { trusted_subnets; };
    allow-query { trusted_subnets; };
};



controls {
    inet 127.0.0.1 port 953 allow { local_host; } keys { rndc-key; };
};

// 
// a caching only nameserver config
// 
zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "caching-example/named.root";
};

zone "localhost" IN {
    type master;
    file "caching-example/localhost.zone";
    allow-update { none; };
};

zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" IN {
    type master;
    file "caching-example/named.local";
    allow-update { none; };
};
zone "skails.home" {
    type master;
    file "/var/named/skails.home.hosts";
    notify yes;
    allow-update { key rndc-key; };
};
zone "12.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/var/named/192.168.12.rev";
    notify yes;
    allow-update { key rndc-key; };
};
```

EDIT:
As suggested I also tried `host <intranet pc name|FQDN> <ip address of server>` and this also worked as expected.
So on a random intranet pc I :

- can ping, nslookup, host, ssh, wget correctly from cli (the cli works)
- cannot access the Apache server (a simple HTTP webpage)

from a mobile phone I:

- can nslookup
- cannot ping, access HTTP, access MPD or any other intranet services.

The curious thing in all these case is that no DNS lookup occurs.

EDIT2: the named.root is not empty:

```
$ cat /var/named/caching-example/named.root | egrep -v "(;)"
.                        3600000      NS    A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     198.41.0.4
A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      AAAA  2001:503:ba3e::2:30
.                        3600000      NS    B.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
B.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     199.9.14.201
B.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      AAAA  2001:500:200::b
.                        3600000      NS    C.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
C.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     192.33.4.12
C.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      AAAA  2001:500:2::c
.                        3600000      NS    D.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
D.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     199.7.91.13
D.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      AAAA  2001:500:2d::d
.                        3600000      NS    E.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
E.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     192.203.230.10
E.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      AAAA  2001:500:a8::e
.                        3600000      NS    F.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
F.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     192.5.5.241
F.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      AAAA  2001:500:2f::f
.                        3600000      NS    G.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
G.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     192.112.36.4
G.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      AAAA  2001:500:12::d0d
.                        3600000      NS    H.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
H.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     198.97.190.53
H.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      AAAA  2001:500:1::53
.                        3600000      NS    I.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
I.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     192.36.148.17
I.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      AAAA  2001:7fe::53
.                        3600000      NS    J.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
J.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     192.58.128.30
J.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      AAAA  2001:503:c27::2:30
.                        3600000      NS    K.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
K.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     193.0.14.129
K.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      AAAA  2001:7fd::1
.                        3600000      NS    L.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
L.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     199.7.83.42
L.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      AAAA  2001:500:9f::42
.                        3600000      NS    M.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
M.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      A     202.12.27.33
M.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.      3600000      AAAA  2001:dc3::35
```

Comment: Check the output of `host internal.host firewall.ip.address`. That should tell you more about the resolution error and where it happens.

Comment: If you use the internet to resolve **zone "." IN** (what is inside named.root? Some internet sever addresses?) then you **do** need internet for anything to work. You would need some root addresses set in files for your (standalone) bind server to work.

Comment: Yes, exactly, your `named.root.` contains **internet** addresses. Nothing will get rexolved without internet. You need to solve that. @nass

Comment: @IsaaC I am still not sure how. should I use and empty file ?

Comment: Doesn't the Digutal Ocean page I linked in my answer have all the information you need? @nass

Comment: @IsaaC maybe  I missed something that but it mentions nothing above `named.root`. Also these are top level DNS resolvers in `named.root` , but I thought since there are ip addresses as well, this is what makes it a standalone server.

Answer (score 1):

The whole description of the [required configuration](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-centos-7) (digital ocean is a quite reputable site) is quite long and has many details. The basic premise is that you must have `dig` (since you are using `bind`) to be able to resolve local names from your local DNS `bind` server. The basic query:

```
$ dig @192.168.12.122 skails.home.      # assuming your server
                                        # is at 192.168.12.122
```

should be correctly resolved by your `bind` server whether there is internet or not.

Please understand that a DNS server might cache received answers. Specially **negative** answers. If the DNS server is trying to resolve a **.** (dot) address or a **home.** address and receives a negative answer, nothing else would be resolved (unless the server itself knows how to bypass such problem). That is why the server needs to be configured as a **standalone** server. The configuration link given above.

Please understand that web addresses that have only **one** dot (*.*) might get directed to mini-dns (or avahi, or others). In short: your local dns address **should not** be **home** (nor local, nor example). A reasonable description is given on [this paper](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-chapin-rfc2606bis-00.html) (which is a draft and not policy, but gives a correct general view of the issue).

The [current BCP (Best current Practice) is this](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2606).

Comment: So I guess the remedy is no resolving for "." zone and , I should switch to a non-prohibited top level (something other than `home.` .

Comment: I guess you are not ready to understand what I am saying.